# Display Loading Image before a page gets loaded completely

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to show a loading image before the content of the whole page is loaded. How to achieve this? I'm working in ASP.NET.

Thank you.
NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initially have the image showing in your HTML, and then hide it when the page loads, like this:

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('loadingImageIDHere').style.display = 'none';
};
```

EDIT: The OP tagged this question as 'javascript', NOT 'jquery'!!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use Javascript to accomplish this. My preference is jQuery. jQuery has a function that executes when the page is fully loaded, so you could set your main content div to have a css property display:none, and then when the DOM is ready, you could use jQuery to show the content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myContent").css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to have a loading image displayed on every page in advance and then use jQuery to hide the image once the page has loaded.  It's up to you whether you want to use `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load`.

```
// assumes you already have a DIV#preloader container on your page centered with a loading image inside 
// of it
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#preloader").hide();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    $("#preloader").hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm binding some values to the controls in the code behind page load. So how to show the image till all the controls get ready?

Comment: You could just move `$('#preloader').hide()` to after your last bind.